# JavaScript HTTP GET request works on Firefox and iPad Safari, but not Mac OS Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I'm putting together a simple web page that presents the user with a jQuery slider to select a value. The 'stop' event from the slider should trigger a GET request that sends the value to a bit of PHP code to handle the response. The user then gets redirected to another page:

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
   var slideValue = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
   $.get('submit.php', { item : slideValue });
   window.location = "thanks.html";
}
```

This works perfectly -- but only if I use Firefox or the iPad version of Safari. Both of these generate HTTP requests that do the job.

The problem is with Mac OS Safari. `slideValue` is correctly set, and the redirect happens -- but for some reason the GET request doesn't do what it ought to, and the PHP code isn't called.

Calling `submit.php?item=<number>` manually from Safari works.

I am new to both JavaScript and jQuery, so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wait the answer of your get request before changing the location !

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
   var slideValue = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
   $.get('submit.php', { item : slideValue },function() {
     window.location = "thanks.html";
   });
}
```

If you use jQuery 1.5, you can use deferred object:

```
stop: function( event, ui ) {
   var slideValue = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
   $.get('submit.php', { item : slideValue })
   .success(function() {
     window.location = "thanks.html";
   })
   .error(function() {
     alert("error");
   });
}
```

Comment: Perfect. It works. You are a scholar and a gentleman -- thank you.

Comment: Now accepted. The site made me wait ten minutes before I could click on the tick. Thanks again.